# How can I control lottie animation in flutter

Tags: flutter-animation

I have a custom made lottie animation for an app I am working on. I want this animation to play only one time. I was following a YouTube tutorial that I found online; however, when I follow it as is I receive an error (while the user in the YT video does not).The error that I receive says "LateInitializationError: Field '_screenController' has not been initialized.

Comment: Follow the tutorial carefully, find where they initialize `_screenController`, probably inside `initState`, you might be missing that line.